# How to skip surefire tests but run failsafe tests?

Tags: maven, unit-testing, maven-surefire-plugin, maven-failsafe-plugin

In my project I have surefire as well as failsafe tests.

If I run with `mvn clean install -DskipTests` then both kinds of tests are skipped.

If I try to run a single failsafe test using -Dit.test=TestName then first all surefire tests run and then my it test.. but as the surefire tests take a long time this is not good.

I would like to skip the surefire tests in some cases but run the failsafe IT tests.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It's sometimes kind of confusing (annoying?) that, by default, `-DskipITs=true` will skip Failsafe but `-DskipTests=true` will skip both Surefire and Failsafe tests.

Anyway, you can change this behaviour by configuring the Surefire plugin to use a different 'skip' parameter. For example:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.12.4</version>
    <configuration>
        <skip>${skipSurefire}</skip>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

This will allow you to skip Surefire tests but **not** Failsafe tests by invoking:

```
mvn clean verify -DskipSurefire=true
```

Comment: Thanks. That helps. It even still allows to do -DskipTests to skip all tests. So this is exactly what I needed.

Comment: Really? That's the part I'm struggling with. I can find all sorts of references on how to set up properties to allow skipping failsafe or surefire independently, but I'm trying to retain the option of using `-DskipTests`, and everything I've tried breaks that.