# configure maven command line args in settings.xml or set in intellij Idea IDEA

Tags: java, maven, intellij-idea

I have multiple projects where I have to pass the following parameters each time.

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\VALUE
-P aws-build 
-DskipTests=TRUE
```

The complete command is:
`mvn -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\VALUE clean install -P aws-build -DskipTests=TRUE`

I am trying to configure it permanently so that I won't have to put it each time I  do `mvn clean install`

I am looking to put settings in settings.xml or anywhere in intellij or any working solution is welcome. The objective is if I run `mvn clean install`, it should pick up those parameters automatically. Thanks!

Comment: You can try adding your VM options under `Settings/Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Build Tools | Maven | Runner | VM Options`

Comment: You can have the profile being activated by default (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6849483/activating-a-profile-by-default), and in surefire/failsafe configure to be have that skip tests always false (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46712510/how-to-skip-surefire-tests-but-run-failsafe-tests). The first property you can do it as it is suggested here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17332857/how-to-use-the-mvn-d-to-set-multiple-properties-in-maven-via-command-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly what `maven.config` file is for. It is located in `/<your_project_dir>/.mvn/maven.config` (create the 'maven.config' file if it doesn't exist). Put all of your custom maven command arguments inside `maven.config` and maven will add your custom command arguments whenever you call Maven, i.e running `mvn clean install` will now include your custom flags.

So, your `maven.config` file will look like:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\VALUE
-P aws-build 
-DskipTests=TRUE
```

Also, side note, `-DskipTests` is sufficient, no need to use `=TRUE`.

From the official [Maven docs](https://maven.apache.org/configure.html#mvn-maven-config-file):

> .mvn/maven.config file:
>
> It’s really hard to define a general set of
> options for calling the maven command line. Starting with Maven
> 3.3.1+, this can be solved by putting this options to a script but this can now simple being done by defining
> `${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/maven.config` file which contains the
> configuration options for the mvn command line.
>
> For example things like `-T3 -U --fail-at-end`. So you only have to call
> Maven just by using `mvn clean package` instead of
> `mvn -T3 -U --fail-at-end clean package` and not to miss the `-T3 -U --fail-at-end options` on every call.
> The `${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/maven.config`
> is located in the `${maven.projectBasedir}/.mvn/` directory; also works
> if in the root of a multi module build.
>
> NOTICE starting with Maven 3.9.0 each single argument must be put in
> new line, so for the mentioned example your file will have content
> like:
>
> ```
> -T3
> -U 
> --fail-at-end
> ```

Answer (score 0):

Got help from a friend:
In Intellij Idea we can do this:
open pom.xml file -> run maven -> new goal -> add the followings in command line:

```
-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=C:\VALUE clean install -P aws-build -DskipTests=TRUE
```

->OK.